# Submit multiple forms using a for loop with a delay (Javascript/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, for-loop

I would like to submit some forms that have similar id's lie form1, form2, etc.

I know that submitting multiple forms at once does not work, and I implemented a setTimeout with if conditionals for each form in part. However, this is very time consuming, and tried to implement a for loop. I am not sure why does not work.

Basically I have 10 inputs with the IDs "input1", "input2"... I managed to save all input values in an array to have easier access to them and check if the value is not null. Each form also has the id of "form1", "form2", ... etc. Also I have a submit all button, which would need to submit all forms.

```
$("#submitAll").click(function () {
   var values = new Array();

   for (i = 0, j = 1; i < 10, j <= 10; i++, j++) {
       values[i] = $('#input' + j).val();
       console.log(values[i]);
       if (values[i].length !== 0) {
          setTimeout(function(){
             $("#form" + j).submit();                   
          }, 1000);
       }
    }
});
```

This (instead of the setTimeout function) does not work either:

```
$("#form" + j).delay(1000).submit();
```

Thanks!

Comment: if u do a form submit then the page loses control and u cant do anything after that. So instead of using the normal form.submit(). I would suggest you to try the ajax form submit in which even after u submit the form u will have the control on the page(to submit the other forms). have a look at the website [link] (https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery)

Comment: @flipper I never used ajax, I am not sure how to use this at the moment. I managed to submit these forms individually before, without a for loop, however, my code would be too large and time-consuming. Is there any other solution?

Comment: am not getting the part that you have done before, because once you hit on $("form").submit() the page control will take over and you cant submit other forms.....?